# Load javascripts via different media querys

Tags: jquery, screen, media

I got some javascript for sliding menus, but I need some values to be different for different size screens.

This is my script for reference:

```
    $('.show-menu').on('click', function () {
        if ($(".menu-button").html() == 'CLOSE') {
            $("#slideover").animate({
                right: "0"
                }, 300);
            $(".black-cover").fadeOut(300);
            $(".menu-button").html('MENU');
                } else {
            $("#slideover").animate({
                right: "512px"
                }, 300);
            $(".black-cover").fadeIn(300);
            $(".menu-button").html('CLOSE');
            }
        });
```

My question is that is it possible to load in .js files scripts similar to the link query below?

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
      media="only screen and (orientation:landscape) and (orientation:portrait)" href="ipad.css">

<link rel="stylesheet"
      media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2) and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)" href="iphone.css">
```

If you need me elaborate the question let me know or if you can think of another solution then awesome, thanks in advance.

---

UPDATE, Thanks for the 3 answers, I can see all of them working a beaut.

I'm going to try them all and repost the one that works the fastest and is lightest :-)

Again, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`window.matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.matchMedia). Here’s a polyfill: https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js

If you want to load different script files based on which media query currently matches, you could combine the above with a script loader like LAB.js or [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/).

Comment: Hey dude, this seemed like the perfect option so I ideally want this to work, do you think you could advise? [matchMedia new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155001/matchmedia-query-and-javascript-not-working-right) thanks, josh

Comment: it's definitely better than mine:)

Comment: It's OK - but I could get it to work directly so as I'm using the HTML 5 Boiler plate for mobile, I just loaded my scripts in like so   `yepnope({
   test : Modernizr.mq('only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5)'),
   yep  : '<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/scripts/menu-mobile.js',
   nope : '<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/scripts/menu-tablet.js',
  });`

Which is ideal anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [animate to class](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/animate-to-class) plugin so I could define the `right` css property within the stylesheets

Answer (score 1):

As you are using media query, you usually will change the width of one element when a media query is triggered

So my solution is based on the effects of your CSS media queries. It **add a listener to `window.resize()` event** and load the scripts **if the width of your layout element has changed**.

For example if you have the following media query code:

```
#changeTarget{
    width: 300px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    #changeTarget{
        width: 420px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #changeTarget{
        width: 600px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    #changeTarget{
        width: 900px;
    }
}
```

Then the javascript goes something like this:

```
var prevWidth; //previous width used for comparison
var detector; //the element used to compare changes

$(document).ready(function(){

    //set the initial values
    detector = $('#changeTarget');
    //Cache this width for later comparison
    prevWidth = detector.width();

    $(window).resize(function(){
        //If a change has happened, record this updated width and load your js
        if(detector.width()!=prevWidth){
            prevWidth = detector.width();

            // Load the JS files

        }

    });

});
```

Comment: This won’t load any JS files until the user actually resizes the browser.